# multiple filter mapping for the same filter

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have 2 web apps deployed in weblogic. since each of them has a separate hibernate session factory.
I use specialServlet in webapp2 to invalidate the 2nd level cache.  `filter1` is used to set up hibernate session so I can call to invalidate the 2nd level cache.

from web app1 I include /servlet/specialServlet which is in  web app2.

I want the `filter1` be called for `/servlet/*` with regular request.

but for `servlet/specialServlet` I want the `filter1` not only be called with regular request but also be called for `include` request.
what is the best way to specify the filter mapping?
Also dose the order of the filter mapping elements matters for `filter1`?

```
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">          
  xxx
                  <filter>
                      <filter-name>filter1</filter-name>
                      <filter-class>xxx</filter-class>
                  </filter>
                  <filter-mapping>
                    <filter-name>filter1</filter-name>
                    <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
                  </filter-mapping>          
                  <filter-mapping>
                    <filter-name>filter1</filter-name>
                    <url-pattern>/servlet/specialServlet</url-pattern>
                    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
                  </filter-mapping>
   xxx
  </web-app>
```

Comment: Why exactly are you asking this rhetorical question? What exactly is the problem you're having with it?

Comment: I want the filter1 get called when I include /servlet/specialServlet from another web app. filter1 did some hibernate setup work.

Comment: I have recently test this scenario and it works. In my case I set different servlet to same filter. And looks to me `filter-mapping` order doesn't matter.